# Extraction of tables and their preceding words

Tags: python, regex, nlp, pypdf, tabula

I have a list of words(it is capital sensitive) and each word appears in a text which sometimes  is followed by a table. I extracted text using pypdf2.

How to pull pairs of each table and given word which appears in text above each table. I want to use tabula and put each pairs of words and table into a dictionary such as key is the given word and value is the related table ? I dont know how to implement it. any help would be so much appreciated.

Text is example of one page of pdf.

> text ='''id: Res ID\nRes ID\nBased upon  3,302 valid cases out of 3,30
> total .\n•Mean:
> 54361.66\n•Minimum: 10005.00\n•Maximum: 99992.00\n•Standard Deviation:
> 25723.74\nLocation: 1-5 (width: 5; decimal: 0)\nVariable Type:  numeric \nVIS: Study \nSwan  visit \nValue Label
> Unweighted\nFrequency%\n00- 3302 100.0 %\n Total 3,302 100%\nBased
> upon  3,302 valid cases out of 3,302 total cases.\nLocation: 6-7
> (width: 2; decimal: 0)\nVariable Type:  character \nINT: Interview
> \nDate form \nValue Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n0- 3302 100.0 %\n
> Total 3,302 100%\nBased upon 3,302 valid  cases out of 3,302 total
> cases.\n•Mean:
> 0.00\n•Median: 0.00\n•Mode: 0.00\n•Minimum:
> 0.00\n•Maximum: 0.00\n•Standard Deviation:
> 0.00\nLocation: 8-8 (width: 1; decimal: 0)\nVariable Type:  numeric'''

```
    import tabula
        lis= ["id","VIS","INT"]
    
        results_dict = {}
        for word in lis:
            if word in text:
                try:
                    table = tabula.read_pdf("df.pdf", pages='all', multiple_tables=True)            
                    results_dict[word] = table
                except:
                    pass
        
        print(results_dict)
```

Update :

Expected output :

```
    dic = {id:"no_table",VIS:Value  Label  Unweighted/Frequency   %
                             00     -            3302            100.0 %
                                    Total        3,302           100%
                         ,INT:Value Label  Unweighted/Frequency   %
                             00     -            3302            100.0 %
                                    Total        3,302           100%
```

the value should be a table that is converted to a data frame.
how should value look:

```
data = {'Value':  ['0.0', 'NaN'],
        'Label': ['-', 'Total'],
        'Unweighted\rFrequency':  ['3302', '3,302'],
        '%': ['100.0 %', '100%'],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output (*how should look like each table*) found in `text` ?

Comment: `table = tabula.read_pdf("df.pdf", pages='all', multiple_tables=True)` What's the return value of this? Is tabula correctly picking up the tables? We don't have your PDF, so we have no idea is this step is working correctly.

Comment: The return value of this is a list of tables. lilke if I print table[0] it gives me the first table and etc

Comment: but the table is already in the form of dataframe

Comment: yes tabula is correctly picking of tables, it is just a list of dataframes which like a list of all tables in from  of data frames.

Comment: Do you think you can help?